# Making knockback in c++

Tags: c++, sdl2

I want to implement a "knockback" in my 2D game, but I have no idea how to do it. I've found some tutorials on google but nothing help. (My knowledge about math is a little limited when we're talking about Cartesian plane)

Well let's just figure out, I have the player and the monster on my map (2 vectors) and when I touch the monster, BOOOM, I get "knockbacked" at the OPPOSITE direction (not left, right, top or bottom) that I touch him.

[image]

[image]

I have the following code on my project:

CollisionManager.cpp

```
CollisionManager::CollisionManager()
{
}


CollisionManager::~CollisionManager()
{
}

bool CollisionManager::checkCollisionWithWall(SDL_Rect box, std::vector<Tile*> tiles)
{
    return touchesWall(box, tiles);
}

void CollisionManager::checkCollisionEnemy(Player * player, GameObject * enemy)
{
    if (enemy->type() == std::string("Enemy"))
    {
        return;
    }
    if (SDL_HasIntersection(&player->getCollisionBox(), &enemy->getCollisionBox()))
    {
        player->collision(enemy);
    }
}
```

The player's collision function (almost nothing here):

```
void Player::collision(GameObject* collisionObject)
{
    isKnockbacking = true;
    hp -= 2;

}
```

Ahh and my moving function is inherited from my Entity class:

```
void Entity::checkTileCollision(std::vector<Tile*> tiles)
{
    if (isKnockbacking == false) {
        //Move the dot left or right
        v2DPosition.m_x += v2DVelocity.m_x;
        collisionBox.x = v2DPosition.m_x;

        //If the dot collided or went too far to the left or right
        if ((v2DPosition.m_x < 0) || 
        (v2DPosition.m_x + 18 > Game::Instance()->getScreenWidth()) || 
        collisionManager->checkCollisionWithWall(collisionBox, tiles))
        {
            //Move back
            v2DPosition.m_x -= v2DVelocity.m_x;
            collisionBox.x = v2DPosition.m_x;
        }

        //Move the dot up or down
        v2DPosition.m_y += v2DVelocity.m_y;
        collisionBox.y = v2DPosition.m_y;

        //If the dot collided or went too far up or down
        if ((v2DPosition.m_y < 0) || 
        (v2DPosition.m_y + 18 > Game::Instance()->getScreenHeight()) || 
        collisionManager->checkCollisionWithWall(collisionBox, tiles))
        {
            //Move back
            v2DPosition.m_y -= v2DVelocity.m_y;
            collisionBox.y = v2DPosition.m_y;
        }
    }
}
```

I've followed LazyFoo, SDL Game Development book and some other tutorials on YouTube to make it.

If I need to be more specific, just tell me.

Comment: We generally expect to see what you have tried to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

To move an object in reverse simply multiply it's velocity by -1, the infrastructure seems to be in place so modifying the collision function should suffice :

```
void Player::collision(GameObject* collisionObject)
{
     isKnockbacking = true;
     hp -= 2;
     v2DPosition += v2DVelocity * -1 * someScalar   
}
```

someScalar could be another number to increase the distance moved.

Comment: This wouldn't work if the player is running away from the enemy.